# Stuck lens off - scared to reattach another lens

Tags: lens, camera

I managed to get my 50mm lens off my camera (it was stuck) and it looks like one of the lens pins was broken. I'm scared to reattach another lens. Was it the camera body that was making the lens stuck or the lens itself. Advice?

Comment: Asking the internet for help is fine, but you really ought to take the body and lens in for an expert human to see in person.

Answer (score -2):

Fixed. The problem was with the lens, not the camera body so there was no issue putting a different lens back on. Thanks!

Comment: Was this a Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 II? This lens is famous for getting stuck on cameras due to a plastic, snap on rear dust cover, that gets dislodged and interferes with rotation during lens removal.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyPAOH2QYig

Comment: My guess: A Ricoh lens on a pentax camera :)

Comment: Or a Nikon "pre-AI" lens with a newer F-mount body with the fixed aperture coupling tab.